# How is regex filter applied to date (isodate) type field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, isodate

I was trying to apply a regex filter(year) to a date type field but the query returned no results. So was trying to understand the behavior of this query?

```
db.collection.find({"ReportedDate":/2016/i})
```

**Note:** I can filter it by date type without regex. But I am just trying to understand the behavior of the regex filter against date type field?

Comment: Data type counts in the filter. Regex is applicable to strings only. It resolves to false for Date, numbers, etc. `find({"ReportedDate":/.*/})` will return only documents where `ReportedDate` is a string.

Comment: @AlexBlex I was thinking in similar line. Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

From MongoDB version >= 4.4 we can write custom filters using [`$function`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) operator so try this:

```js
let yearRegex = /2016/i;

db.collection.find({
    $expr: {
        $function: {
            body: function(reportedDate, yearRegex) {
                return yearRegex.test(reportedDate);
            },
            args: [{ $toString: "$ReportedDate" }, yearRegex],
            lang: "js"
        }
    }
});
```

**Note**: Instead of [`$toString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) we can also use [`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) with `timezone` to cover edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the [$regex query operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) provides regular expression capabilities for pattern matching *strings* in queries.

An alternative to using regex filter to query the `year` value, you can utilise [MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) to project the year portion of a date object using [$year aggregation operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/). 
For example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
     {"$addFields": {"year": {"$year":"$ReportedDate" } } }, 
     {"$match": {"year": 2016 } }
], {cursor:{batchSize:10}})
```

There are other useful date related operators such as: [$dayOfYear](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfYear/), [$dayOfWeek](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfWeek/), [$dayOfMonth](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfMonth/), etc.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing but instead of find method, I use aggregation pipeline

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project: {
                "d":  { $dateToString: {format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$mydate"}},key:1
            }
        }  ,
        {
            $match: {
                d: /2012-/i
            }
        }
    ]
    )
```

By this I am able to apply the regex pattern in ISO Date too.